# Process distribution which is a Markov chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

A Markov chain $(ξ_n,n ∈ \mathbb{Z}_+)$ has an initial state $ξ_0 = 0$ and transient probabilities $P(ξ_{n+1} = k+1| ξ_n = k) = p, P(ξ_{n+1} = k| ξ_n = k) = 1 − p, k,n ∈ \mathbb{N}, p ∈ [0,1]$. I find the distribution $ξ_n$.

I do not understand how to calculate the distribution of this process. I had an idea to find a stationary distribution, but since the phase space for a given Markov chain is natural numbers, I cannot write down the transition probability matrix and write down linear relations for stationary distributions. Can anyone help? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\xi_n \in \{0,1,2,\ldots,n\}$. For $k, 0\le k \le n$ we must have $k$ times $ \uparrow$ and $n-k$ times $\to$. We can do this in $C_n^k$ ways.

Comment: Then why the information that this process is a Markov chain were given, any ideas?

Comment: You can write the transition matrix an then multiply it n times to get the same answer. The matrix is infinite and has $p$ on the main diagonal and $1-p$ on the diagonal above.

Comment: But that's the problem. I do not understand how to write transition matrix. Could you explain?

Comment: You can write the transition matrix an then multiply it n times to get the same answer. The matrix is infinite and has p
 on the main diagonal and 1−p
 on the diagonal above.